# Get Rad Numeric Textbox value?

Tags: c#, telerik, rad

Here i'm going to get RAD Numeric textbox value in client side.but failed.There's no any error shown.Here i use alert for testing purpose

My code as follow,(Here i tries 2 ways )

```
alert($find('<%=Live_count.ClientID%>').get_textBoxValue());

alert($find('<%=Live_count.ClientID%>').get_value());
```

The above thing i got it from here [Link](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-radnumerictextbox.html)

Comment: what does the alert give you? or does it even show up?

Comment: the second one should work perfectly for you :/ check the your textbox id is copied right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function OnClientValueChanged(sender, args)
  {
logEvent(GetServerId(sender.get_id()) + ".OnClientValueChanged: Value is changed to " +   args.get_newValue());
   }
```

check client side demo :http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/programming/clientside/apievents/defaultcs.aspx
    and : http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction.html